# uploading file validation with yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to upload a file and I set the rule bellow,the problem is that even I select a file there is the error Please upload a file.what is wrong,as I notice there is something with validation rule,I have done as [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)

`[['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => FALSE,'on'=>'new']`,

At controller I set

```
 $type = new \app\models\Buildobjects();
        $type->scenario="new";
```

[edit] my controller is

```
if ($type->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $type->validate()) {
            $type->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($type, 'file');
            $up = $this->generateRandomString(3);
            if (isset($type->file)) {
                if ($type->upload($up, $type->file)) {
                    $type->file = $up . $type->file->baseName . '.' . $type->file->extension;
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    //return;
                }
            }
            $type->save();
            $this->redirect(Url::to(['site/archive', 'param' => $param]), 302);
        }
```

Comment: What does your Buildobjects model look like? Are you loading the file correctly with `UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file');`

Comment: Are You sure you defined scenario "new" in `scenarios()`?

Comment: As I post I set [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => FALSE,'on'=>'new'] and $type->scenario="new";

Comment: this is help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700919/image-are-save-in-folder-but-not-saved-in-database-in-yii2-0/35702204#35702204

Comment: When I delete the line && $type->validate() the error does not exist,something exist with validation